# Using the shell Method to set up integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

More specifically, I am having trouble setting up the following integral using the shell method.

$y=\frac{1}{x}\space$  $,y=0$  $,x=1$  $,x=4$  $,about $   $y=1$

So far I have:

$2\pi\int(1-y)(\frac{1}{y})dy$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The volume of a shell is $dV=2\pi r h dy$ where:

$r=1-y$ is the distance of a point of the hyperbola from the line $y=1$

$h=4-\frac{1}{y}$ is the distance from the point of the Hyperbola to the line $x=4$

and the limits for $y$ are $\frac {1}{4} \le y \le 1$